# Проблема со сложением в калькуляторе Jquery

Tags: javascript, калькулятор

Необходимо посчитать сумму  платежа по формуле:
(Сумма займа * процентную ставку * кол-во месяцев + сумму займа)

Использую данный код,

```
$("#summa").text(Math.round($("#hidden").val() * $("#hidden2").val() * q + $("#hidden").val()));
```

но в нем косячит оператор +, он не прибавляет значение а добавляет к получившемуся числу еще число. т.е. работает как 'число' + 'второе число'

Comment: Ты складываешь строки, вот у тебя и проблема, попробуй сделать parseInt или parseFloat

Comment: Оператор + не косячит, косячит незнание типа данных.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы вставляли не числа, а строки (т.е. текстовые поля). Вам нужно преобразовать все строки в числа с помощью `Number`

```js
$(function() {
  var q = 4;
  $("#summa").text(Math.round(Number($("#hidden").val()) * Number($("#hidden2").val()) * q + Number($("#hidden").val())));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<div id="summa"></div>
<input id="hidden" value="2">
<input id="hidden2" value="3">
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: @ДанилШуваев, тогда отметь ответ, как правильный

Comment: извиняюсь, только начал пользоваться данным сервисом, не знал что так надо, вроде подтвердил...На галочку нажать надо, верно?

Comment: @ДанилШуваев, да. Ну это формальность. Это делается, что бы пользователи, у которых схожие проблемы знали, что вам помогло. Ну и автору +15 в репутацию начисляется за эту формальность )

Answer (score 0):

Оберните каждую операцию получения значения в скобки и умножьте на 1, что бы ваша строка стала числом.

```
($("#hidden").val() * 1)
```

Comment: Или, как вариант, по идее, сработает `+$("#hidden").val()`.